# Whitelist domain address instead of outbound IP address for Azure functions

Tags: azure, networking, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

I have created an Azure Function on Consumption Plan and wish to connect to a 3rd party SFTP location. From Azure documentation I understand that with Consumption Plan, the effective number of outbound IP Addresses I would need to whitelist is over 400 for my region. Instead of switching to expensive Dedicated Plan, is it fine if I ask the 3rd Party SFTP maintainers to whitelist Azure Function domain name: <function-app-name>.azurewebsites.net? Is this a suitable workaround to avoid expensive Dedicated Plan with virtual network configuration (or even worse idea of whitelisting 400+ possible outbound IP addresses)?

Comment: I don't think that would work. I haven't done this before, but can't you just route your traffic through a Vnet with a static IP, is that expansive?

Comment: @Mocas VNET is not that expensive, but Consumption Plan does not allow VNET configuration. You need to switch to Dedicated Plan to be able to configure VNET and Dedicated Plans are expensive, especially for my usecase where execution is effectively once a day for a few seconds.